# React Error - 'deleteNinja' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to delete state data by Id I passed the function as a props. but I am getting error in Ninja.js file saying-

Failed to compile

src\Ninjas.js
Line 11:41:  'deleteNinja' is not defined  no-undef

I don't understand why I am getting error.

App.js file-

```js
import Ninjas from './Ninjas';
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddNinja from './AddNinja';

function App() {
  const [ ninjas , setNinja ] = useState([
    { name: 'Pratik', age: 23, belt:'Black', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Yash', age: 20, belt:'Green', id: 2 },
    { name: 'Smit', age: 20, belt:'Pink', id: 3 }
  ]) ;
  const addNinja = (ninja) => {
    ninja.id = Math.random();
    setNinja([...ninjas , ninja]);
   };
   const deleteNinja = (id) => {
    setNinja(ninjas.filter(ninja => {
     return ninja.id !== id
    }));
   };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>My First react App</h1>
        <Ninjas ninjas = { ninjas } deleteNinja = { deleteNinja } />
       <AddNinja addNinja = { addNinja } />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Ninja.js file :-

```js
import React from 'react';

const Ninjas = ({ ninjas }) => {
   
        const ninjaList = ninjas.map(ninja => {
            return ninja.age > 19 ? (
                <div className="ninja" key = { ninja.id }>
                <div>Name: { ninja.name }</div>
                <div>Age: { ninja.age }</div>
                <div>Belt: { ninja.belt }</div>
                <button onClick={() => {deleteNinja(ninja.id) }}>Delete Ninja</button>
            </div>
            )
            : null;
        })
        return(
            <div className='ninja-list'>
                { ninjaList }
            </div>
            
        )
}

export default Ninjas;
```

Comment: this will fix the error.
 const Ninjas = ({ ninjas , deleteNinja}) => {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `deleteNinja` prop in `Ninjas` component.

Change code like below:

```
...
const Ninjas = ({ ninjas, deleteNinja }) => {
...
```